# Circular dependency in build pipeline on Teamcity

Tags: continuous-integration, teamcity, build-automation

Simplified we have two configurations on TC for our C# project:

- Build
- Issue closed

**Build**
Will be triggered after a commit to the svn repository.
Updates the assembly version (Assembly info patcher)
Generates the binaries.

**Issue closed**
Manually triggered if a issue (story/bug) has been finished.
Triggers a new **Build**
Takes the build products from **Build** and publishs them on a network drive.

What I would like know is that the **Build** configuration takes the build number of the **Issue closed** configuration and uses it as part of the version number used in the assembly info patcher

Unfortunately its not possible with snapshot dependencies, because then I would have a circular dependecy.
I also tried to use a file containing the **Issue closed** build number, but then I can not pass this number to the assembly info pacher.